# Algorithm for determining the size of an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

**How does one determine the length of an array in an effective manner?**

While looking for a way to get the size of an array or global in Intersystems Cache I started thinking of how to actually determine the array size.  I have since found a solution to my original problem, but the puzzle of determining the size of an array effectively is still bugging me, so here is what I came up with so far:

1. Start at index 1.
2. Test for a value at the current index.
3. If a value is found, double the index.
4. If no value is found subtract the second-to-last index used.
5. Continue with step 4, halving the subtracted value on each iteration until the index is small enough for a value to be found again.
6. Increment the index by one untill no value is found.
7. The second-last index will be the size.

As an example, lets take an array of size 52:

```
1  - OK
2  - OK
4  - OK
8  - OK
16 - OK
32 - OK
64 - OVER
48 - OK (64-16)
49 - OK
50 - OK
51 - OK
52 - OK
53 - OVER
```

This seems fair, since I get the length of the array in 13 iterations, however, if my array size increases to 63 it would increase the iterations by 10 - the same size the array increased with.

For a fairly small array I can consider the knock I take on the last few loops to be almost acceptable, even if the array length is only one less than a power of two, but what happens if I use a very large array, say with 2097152 (2^21 - 1)  elements?  That means I'm going to hit the first "over" in 21 iterations, bring the index down to 1572864 and start a VERY LONG LOOP (1572864 iterations).  With this example I am not exactly "winning" all that much.

Now I can optomize this by once again increasing the index in powers of two, but all of this made me wonder:  Is there a better way of doing it?  Am I even remotely on the right track?  Would I be better off simply using a static increase size?

Comment: what language? some language uses structure that explicitly stores the array size, thus is always just a value reading operation

Comment: Yes, that would be the ideal solution since there is no iteration.  I'm just wondering about a good algorithm in general, so for the sake of argument let's assume that we cannot simply store the array size.  :)

Comment: If you don't have the size of the array how do you know where the last element is ?  Your example *begs the question* -- you can't get away with assuming that the size of the array is 52 and then derive an algorithm for finding that size.  You have to start with the assumption that you (and your algorithm) don't know the size of the array.

Comment: What you are talking about is called binary search. You don't need to start going linear after the first overflow. You can keep getting the middle address between the last OK and OVER addresses. Note that in general this is not possible since the OVER case usually ends up with a segmentation fault.

Comment: I seriously don't see how this could be implemented without breaking/bending some memory accessing rules. So is developing such an algorithm necessary/worth the effort?

Comment: @boxed__l: This is more of a theoretical question than anything else, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to reinvent [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search).  In your example, once 64 has failed, you're doing a binary search on the interval between 32 and 64.  So after 48, the next value you should try is 56.  After 56 fails, you go back down to 52.

In general, you should be able to get the size of an array of up to 2^n elements in at most 2n iterations.

Comment: Fair enough.  I initially tried to think of a way to impliment the power of a binary search.

Comment: Binary search only works when you have a floor and a ceiling to search between. You have that when you've found the smallest `n` for which `2^n` is too small and `2^(n+1)` is too large.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of stepping through the last 2^(n-1) through (2^n)-1, do a binary search of that space instead. So *basically* your last suggestion.... Either way, you definitely don't want to go with a static increase size.

Random observation: [Cache ObjectScript](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20131/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GGBL_intro) looks horrible to work with.

Comment: So far it's not too bad.  It has a very ugly syntax, but I suppose I'll get used to it.  I don't work with it that often, though.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your algorithm a bit.

```
1 Start at index 0.
2 Add 1 to index
4 Stash it
5 Test for a value at the current index.
6 If 
   a value is found, double the index, go to 4
   else - if 
        current index = stashed index + 1, stashed index is the size of array, quit
        else set the current index to a stashed value, go to 2
```

This will work effectively not only until the first "over", but untill the end.

Comment: Yes, unless I'm mistaken, this is more or less what I had in mind with the first sentence of my last paragraph.

Comment: Yes, indeed. And it is basically the same binary search, but turned inside out.

Answer (score 0):

In Cache IF you are looking for the size of a single dimension array with an integer index all you need to do is

W $Order(Array(""),-1)

The problem comes if your array is not integers or is multidimensional...